# How to fix sql query problem with two or more position which have one ID

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have sql query where I have to join three tables. One of this is a table with data of invoice, it looks like this:

INVOICE

```
ID CUSTOMER_NAME TAXID        NUMBER       LABEL   GUID
1  CUSTOMER1     8739281100   FV001/2019   1       04EABFB3-0B9D-4749-B99D-A4EBEE079633
```

POSITION OF INVOICE

```
ID ID_INV   POSITION_NAME   COUNT
1  1        NAME1           3
2  1        NAME2           2,5
```

TABLE WITH LABEL

```
ID NAME     VALUE  GUID_INV
1  LABEL1   true   04EABFB3-0B9D-4749-B99D-A4EBEE079633
```

When I want to run this query I have statement like this multiple rows in singleton select.

This is for Firebird 2.5.

```
SELECT 
a.ID,
a.GUID,
a.NUMBER,  
a.CUSTOMER_NAME,
b.COUNT,
(select usrd.LABEL from USER_FIELD_DEFS usrd 
where usrd.GUID_INV=a.GUID and (usrd.ID=1 and usrb.VALUE='true')) as LABEL_NAME
FROM INVOICE a
join POSITION_INVOICE b ON a.ID=b.ID_INV
```

I want to get result like this

```
1 04EABFB3-0B9D-4749-B99D-A4EBEE079633 FV001/2019 CUSTOMER1 3   LABEL1
1 04EABFB3-0B9D-4749-B99D-A4EBEE079633 FV001/2019 CUSTOMER1 2,5 LABEL1
```

Please help with this. I know that solution maybe is very simple but I have some eclipse of the mind:)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the output. I think you might need to change the following: `usrb.VALUE='true'` to `usrd.VALUE='true'`

Comment: What do you mean with _"When I want to run this query I have statement like this multiple rows in singleton select."_? Did you mean you get the error _"multiple rows in singleton select"_? If so, please show the content of `USER_FIELD_DEFS`, most likely it produces **multiple** rows for the given condition of that sub-select.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the rows you want based on the 3 tables you provided. If there is a chance that an invoice has no position then simply replace the inner join with left join

```
SELECT
I.[Id]
,I.[GUID]
,I.[NUMBER]
,I.[CUSTOMER_NAME]
,IP.[POSITION_NAME]
,L.[NAME]
FROM [INVOICE] I
INNER JOIN [IN_P] IP ON IP.ID_INV = I.Id
LEFT JOIN [LABEL] L ON L.[GUID_INV] = I.[GUID]
```

Comment: The use of `[` and `]` are SQL Server (and IIRC Sybase) specific syntax, the SQL standard quote character for identifiers is `"`, and Firebird supports this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Antonios Katopodis. Properly my query is more complex, and I have there eight tables, but your solution give me a breathe and I can finish my work with this query. Thanks one more time.

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing one more `join` here. Assuming `USER_FIELD_DEFS` is the same as TABLE WITH LABEL that you have mentioned here

```
SELECT 
a.ID,
a.GUID,
a.NUMBER,  
a.CUSTOMER_NAME,
b.COUNT,
c.NAME
FROM INVOICE a
JOIN POSITION_INVOICE b ON a.ID=b.ID_INV
JOIN USER_FIELD_DEFS c ON c.GUID_INV = a.GUID AND c.ID=1 and c.VALUE='true'
```